# Need to published code run in localhost of nopcommerce 3.90

Tags: c#, nopcommerce-3.90

I have published code of nopcommerce 3.90 which is release mode.

I want to run that code in my end with localhost.

also need to open that code in Visual studio 2022.

Does anyone know how to run that published code with localhost and open in visual studio?

Comment: Do you understand what publishing is?

Comment: @FortyTwo, Yes. I am taking from server source code and that code need to run in my end my machine with local host.
I am sure on server source code published with release mode.
Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I opened that published code in Visual Studio 2022. But while I didn't build that code, it means that many references and versioning issues appear.

One more thing I checked with Release|debug mode. It raised an error while running the project.

That means it still doesn't work with localhost.